# Алгоритм не начинается сначала

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Имеется вот такой код

```js
var cvs = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var block = new Image();
var bg = new Image();

block.src = 'block.png';
bg.src = 'bg.png';

var x = 240;
var lessX = -2;
var addX = 2;

var y = 10;
var addY = -2;
var lessY = 2;

function usl(){
  if(x > 10){
    x += lessX;
  }

  if(x <= 10){
    x = 10;
    addX = 0;
    y += lessY;
  }
  if(y >= 340){
    y = 340;
    lessY = 0;
    lessX = 0
    addX = 2;
    x += addX;
  }
  if(x >= 240){
    x = 240;
    addX = 0;
    y += addY;
  }
}

function draw(){
  ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);
  ctx.drawImage(block, x, y);
  usl();
  if(x == 240 && y == 10){
    usl();
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

bg.onload = draw;
```

В функции draw() стоит условие, которое, по идее, должно запускать алгоритм заново ( квадратик встает в ту же самую точку, откуда и начинал, и предыдущие условия должны на нем работать ( то есть он снова должен пойти влево ) ).

```
if(x == 240 && y == 10){
    usl();
  }
```

Но он не идет. В чем может быть проблема ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно вернуть начальные значения для переменных lessX, addX, lessY и addY, чтобы ваш квадратик принял исходное направление

```
if (x == 240 && y == 10) {
    lessX = -2;
    addX = 2;
    lessY = 2;
    addY = -2;
}
```

Это условие лучше из `draw` перенести в конец функции `usl`, поскольку она у вас вычисляет позицию квадратика, а в `draw` оставить только рисование и вызов `usl`:

```
function draw(){
    ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(block, x, y);
    usl();

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```